# Iterate through a dictionary with a list

Tags: ansible

I would like to know if there is a way to iterate through a dictionary whose value is a list.

I have a variable as:

```
dict_var: {"key1": [value1,value2,value3], "key2": [value4,value5,value6]}
```

My task looks something like this:

```
- name: "Print key and value"
debug:
  msg: "{{item.key}} and {{item.value}}"
with_dict: "{{ dict_var }}"
```

The above task prints the output as:

```
key1 and [value1,value2,value3]    
key2 and [value4,value5,value6]
```

Is there a way to print the output as below?

```
key1 and value1   
key1 and value2   
key1 and value3   
key2 and value4   
key2 and value5   
key2 and value6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the thing you are looking for is [`product`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.2/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py#L200) (which is just the jinja filter of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product))

```
debug:
  msg: '{{ item.0 }} and {{ item.1 }}'
loop: |
  {% set r = [] %}
  {% for k in dict_var %}
  {%   set x = [k] | product(dict_var[k]) | list %}
  {%   set _ = r.extend(x) %}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ r }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Then please accept the answer, as it lets others know you no longer need help